# Advice wanted on best way to handle "tags" in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags

Would like to implement some solution for adding tags to a certain user profile and using these tags also in my app itself. What would be a good tags gems to handle all the tags in an rail app and let users also pick existing tags or add new ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your needs:

[acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)

or

[acts_as_taggable_on_steroids](https://github.com/jviney/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids)

both are great depending on exacly what you require form you tagging